# Wide Search alike function that is supposed to give two lists back, one with visited items and one without

Tags: python

In the following Function I tried to simulate an wide search alike function.

First Function 'Hello' by giving and search name = V, is supposed to give you all the tuple partners that it has in a list.

Second Function is supposed to have two lists, first for already visited and the ones who are still in a list i.e. `que`.

With two for loops I went through newly generated list by the word given in, so that I can use those words to generate further tuple partners, that aren't in `besucht` list. After the usage has been done the item will be deleted from the 'Liste' and appended to `besucht`.

**Question**: It doesn't work as I intended and I don't understand why

```
V = {'CGN', 'FRA','KEL','MUC','PAD','SFX','STR','TXL'}

E = {('SFX','TXL'),('FRA','CGN'),('FRA','MUC'),('FRA','STR'),('CGN','FRA'),('STR','FRA'),('TXL','SFX'),('CGN','PAD'),('PAD','KEL'),('MUC','KEL'),('KEL','STR')   }
S = {('A','B'),('A','B')}

def Hallo(V,E):
    Total = []
    Que = []
    for i in E:

        for j in i:
            if j == V:
                Total.append(i)

    for i in Total:
        for a in i:
            if a != V:
                if a not in Que:

                    Que.append(a)

    return Que


def Durchsuchen(V,E):
    besucht = []
    Liste = []
    Liste.append(Hallo(V,E))
    besucht.append(V)

    while len(Liste) !=0

        for i in Liste:
            if i not in besucht:
                besucht.append(i)
                Liste.remove(i)
                Liste.append(Hallo(i,E))





    print Liste
    print  besucht


print Durchsuchen('FRA',E)
```

**What is supposed to do?** It's supposed to give you all the possibilities i.e if you give in 'FRA' it will generate [MUC, STR, CGN] since MUC and etc is within this list this should also give you KEL for example. I.E all the possible options that are out there.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Well your problem is that you use remove() on a list inside a loop that iterates through it - which should never be done. This changes the logic that the loop relies on and causes your unexpected results.

The first function works just fine so I'd suggest you to use it once on your first word 'FRA', and then use it on every word that pairs with it - [MUC, STR, CGN] in your example. Then use the following code on the lists that you got:

```
newList = []
    for ls in listOfLists:
        for word in ls:
            if word not in newList:
                newList.append(word)
```